# Including Directories in Locate on Mac OS X

Tags: osx, locate

Can anybody shed light on which directories OS X decides to put in the locate database and which it decides to omit?  It's pretty clear that `~/Library` is out - which others?  And how do I modify this so that every time `updatedb` is called, it actually scans all my directories?

This question has (sort of) been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298075/locate-does-not-return-hits-for-content-of-library), but it wasn't answered well, and the question of default directories for the (`cron` task?) `updatedb` never even came up.

Comment: Have you looked at `/etc/updatedb.conf`?

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS 10.10.2, look at `/etc/locate.rc` file for the `PRUNEPATHS` field. From [Apple's man page for locate.updatedb](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/locate.updatedb.8.html):

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The `locate.updatedb` utility updates the database used by `locate(1)`. 
>   It is typically run once a week by the
>   `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist` job. The contents
>   of the newly built database can be controlled by the `/etc/locate.rc`
>   file.

**Correction**: The above link and quoted content is for Mac OS 10.9. The setup appears to be same in OS 10.10.2.

Answer (score -1):

Your ~/Library, ~/Documents, ~/Applications ... etc are all created with 700 as permission. Locate will skip them. If you want them to be included in your locate database, change the permission to 755.

```
chmod 755 ~/Library
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```